# RESTful Service randomly returns after 60 seconds

Tags: angularjs, apache, rest, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

I have an AngularJS front end that calls a RESTful service (GET) to pull data into my web application. The service layer is Jersey on Tomcat 7 (Apache Web Server) with Hibernate, Spring, and a Postgres database. The data load and volume are very light on a load balanced AWS environment over SSL.

These services typically take ~200 milliseconds to complete. However, every X number of requests will sit in 'pending status' (Chrome Developer Tools) then finally return after exactly 1 minute. This is not a timeout - the expected data IS returned which is especially odd. It doesn't appear there is any sequence of events of specific calls (there are 4 API calls) that trigger this activity. Have not been able to reproduce. Seems to be consistent across browsers and network traffic seems to indicate the browser is sending the request right away.

Thoughts? As I mentioned, the odd thing is the data DOES return after 1 minute when they get hung up.

Comment: It can be related to http thread pool of tomcat or connection pool size of database etc.. If you send more request than size of pool the last requests should wait for finishing the first ones.

Comment: Good call out. I checked the DB configs on all servers and they should be significant and confirmed lower than active connections on the DB. The Tomcat connections are default which should also be sufficient based on the volume I'm seeing - plus no errors in the log. Would this explain the exact 60 second return time?